# Como faço para matar um websocket?

Tags: java, websocket

Estou com dificuldades para **matar o websocket** que roda dentro do meu aplicativo em java, não consigo achar respostas em nenhum lugar.

Preciso disso, pois, estou usando ele com uma extensão do chrome para preencher forms de um site, mas quando atualizo a página ou a fecho e abro novamente o servidor para de enviar novas informações ao form, então quero reinicia-lo quando necessário.

**Classe *ServidorExt*:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package servidor;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ClientHandshake;
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;
import view.painelUsuarios;

/**
 *
 * @author Neto
 */
public class ServidorExt extends WebSocketServer {

    public static String msg1;
    public static String msg2;
    public static String msg3;

    public void Verificador() {
        painelUsuarios pu = new painelUsuarios();
        msg1 = pu.getMsg1();
    }

    public void PegaMsg1() {
        msg1 = painelUsuarios.getMsg1();
    }

    public void PegaMsg2() {
        msg2 = painelUsuarios.getMsg2();
    }

    public void PegaMsg3() {
        msg3 = painelUsuarios.getMsg3();
    }

    public ServidorExt(int porta) throws UnknownHostException {
        super(new InetSocketAddress(porta));
        System.out.println("Recebendo conexões da porta: " + porta);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String mensagem) {

        String msgAnterior = "";
        String msgNova;

        while (true) {

            Verificador();
            msgNova = msg1;

            while (!msgNova.equals(msgAnterior)) {
                Verificador();
                msgAnterior = msg1;

                PegaMsg1();
                webSocket.send(msg1);
                System.out.println("msg 1 = "+ mensagem);

                PegaMsg2();
                webSocket.send(msg2);
                System.out.println("msg 2 = "+ mensagem);

                PegaMsg3();
                webSocket.send(msg3);
                System.out.println("msg 3 = "+ mensagem);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(WebSocket arg0, int arg1, String arg2, boolean arg3) {
        System.out.println("A conexão foi encerrada.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(WebSocket arg0, Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro de conexão." + e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, ClientHandshake arg1) {
        System.out.println("Foi iniciado uma nova conexão.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("Servidor iniciado com sucesso!");
    }

}
```

Essa classe é acionada pelo comando `new ServidorExt(8080).start();` em outra classe no aplicativo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com o JavaDoc da classe [WebSocketServer](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/server/WebSocketServer.java) que me parece que você está usando, basta usar o método `stop` no seu servidor.

O problema é que, quando você faz `new ServidorExt(8080).start();`, você está jogando fora a referência ao servidor que você está iniciando. Salve a referência em uma variável pra poder chamar `stop()` nela depois. Por exemplo:

```
public class MinhaOutraClasse {

    private ServidorExt servidor;

    // .....

    public void iniciarServidor() {
        this.servidor = new ServidorExt(8080);
        this.servidor.start()
    }

    public void pararServidor() {
        this.servidor.stop()
    } 

    // ....

}
```

Nesse exemplo, você chama `iniciarServidor()` quando quiser iniciar e `pararServidor()` quando quiser parar.

Comment: Você não sabe o quanto eu procurei por isso, muito obrigado pela ajuda, outra coisa, sabe me informar o porque do servidor para de enviar novas informações ao cliente em javascript quando fecho o navegador e abro novamente, já que o mesmo encontra-se conectado ao servidor?

Comment: Sinto muito, não entendo muito do lado do Javascript. Mas fique à vontade para abrir outra pergunta aqui no site, colocando o código do lado do JavaScript e explicando a situação.

Comment: Tudo bem, já fiz isso, com toda a explicação do meu problema, mas infelizmente ninguém respondeu, mas você já foi de uma grande ajuda, obrigado!